# Getting settings from backend configuration in TYPO3

Tags: controller, typo3, backend, extbase, flexform

I have an own extension (created with extension-builder). In the backend I have different options that I can choose when I edit my plugin. How can I access them in PHP especially from a controller context?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: See also the official documentation on Flexforms: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/FlexForms/Index.html See section "How to read and write flexforms from PHP"

Answer (score 4):

When you use the `settings.` prefix in your plugin's FlexForm you can access them via `$this->settings` in the Extbase controller just as you would access TypoScript plugin settings. FlexForm settings get overlaid onto TypoScript's `tx_xxxx.plugin.settings`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19703365/2819581 for an example.